# I reinstalled MikTEX and installed it but i can't load the .bib file again?

Tags: bibliographies

I uninstalled MikTex and installed it. Now, when i want to add `.bib` file to Winedt I face this warning:

> LaTeX Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 11

I searched for a good solution, but I couldn't find.

My tex code is like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{RN34,
   author = {Hu, Xiaoqing and Bao, Ming and Zhang, Xiao-Ping and Guan, Luyang and Hu, Yu Hen},
   title = {Generalized Iterated Kalman Filter and its Performance Evaluation},
   journal = {IEEE Trans. Signal Processing},
   volume = {63},
   number = {12},
   pages = {3204-3217},
   year = {2015},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{RN34}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{FinalSpringerRefs}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{Ref1}
Hu, X., Hu, Y.-H., Xu, B.: Generalised Kalman filter tracking with multiplicative measurement noise in a wireless sensor network. IET Signal Processing 8(5), 467-474 (2013).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and my `.bbl` file contains:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{0}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL }
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{DOI~\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{DOI~\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup
  \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi
\providecommand{\eprint}[2][]{\url{#2}}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a missunderstanding!

If you use `\bibliography{}` you need not to add your following code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{Ref1}
Hu, X., Hu, Y.-H., Xu, B.: Generalised Kalman filter tracking with multiplicative measurement noise in a wireless sensor network. IET Signal Processing 8(5), 467-474 (2013).

\end{thebibliography}
```

Delete that in your mwe to get (see the changed parameter for `\bibliography` please to fit your created bib file with `filecontents`)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{RN34,
   author = {Hu, Xiaoqing and Bao, Ming and Zhang, Xiao-Ping and Guan, Luyang and Hu, Yu Hen},
   title = {Generalized Iterated Kalman Filter and its Performance Evaluation},
   journal = {IEEE Trans. Signal Processing},
   volume = {63},
   number = {12},
   pages = {3204-3217},
   year = {2015},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{RN34}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{\jobname} % <=============================================


\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting bibliography]

Comment: I simulate this code but i just see "[?]" and there is not any References list in bottom of page

Comment: Well, then you did not follow the usual compiling chain: `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `bibtex mwe` (no extension here!), `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `pdflatex mwe.tex`, right?

Comment: yeah you are right. I'm a beginner and I can't find bibtex mwe

Comment: Well, the simplest way to do that is to open an terminal/console, go to the directory you have your tex file and run the three commands as I mentioned above in my comment ... Or find out how you can run `bibtex` with your used editor you did not told us ...